# What should I do if an edit invalidates my flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, edits

So I recently flagged a question for being Off-Topic on the grounds that it was asking for a tutorial. However, a recent edit removed that portion of the question. Obviously my flag no longer applies, but it's still active and pending review.

What's the best course of action to take in this situation? Is there a way to remove the flag before a moderator reviews it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flags [can now be retracted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334046/635608)

---

<strike>There's nothing you can do. Close votes can be retracted, but flags cannot.</strike>

Close flags send questions to the review queue, not to diamond mods. If the question shouldn't be closed, it likely will not be, and your flag will eventually get dismissed.

So don't worry about it and move on.

Comment: Strangely that flag ended up being deemed "helpful". But thanks for the advice. I guess it's not really that big of a deal.

Comment: That's no longer the case. See the other answer.

Answer (score 22):

You can now retract your flags, see the [help section on post flagging privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Basically, you have a [*Retract Flag*] button on the *flag* dialog on the question/answer:
[image: Flag dialog with Retract Flag button]

Comment: But you (currently) can't retract with the intention to re-target your original flag - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333542/retracted-flag-does-not-let-me-flag-again