# Can I retract a flag posted for a question or answer?

Tags: support, flags

If I flag an answer as "*very low quality*", and then after some time the answer is edited and no longer qualifies as "*very low quality*", is there anything I can do to retract the flag?

Comment: See also: [Add ability to cancel flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252155/3524344)

Answer (score 6):

**Flags [can now be retracted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334046/635608)**

---

**Original answer:**

Flags once raised cannot be taken back. You cannot retract your flags.

In this case, no need to retract the VLQ flag because it will automatically be marked as *disputed* when the post is edited.

Reference: [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag/95277#95277)

> An edit on a post will result in any "Very Low Quality" flags attached to it being disputed. This is because "Very Low Quality" flags are intended for posts that are unsalvageable, and an edit to the post suggests that there's a chance it could still be saved.

Comment: The current behavior is that editing will actually mark it as *helpful*. That page is outdated. See [Community downvotes posts that were just fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236883/community-downvotes-posts-that-were-just-fixed)