# Retracted flag does not let me flag again

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, retracted-flags

**For the purpose of this question, knowing and / or discussing the flag and / or post is not helpful. Thus discussing it or bringing it to light has no use.**

I recently flagged a question, marking it as too broad, when stupidly enough I should have marked it simply as low quality. So I retracted my flag with the purpose of flagging it with what I believe to be the correct reason yet I soon realized I could no longer flag the same post:

[image]

I'd like to know why it is no longer possible to *re-flag* and whether the case should actually be to allow it. I can see that my retracted flag is in the list of flagged posts on my profile yet marked as *self-removed* yet it is not stated whether these are still kept in the review list and so I don't know if the post in question is actually going to be looked at, which is a concern because I feel as if the post should still be flagged and reviewed.

Basically:

If my retracted flag is no longer reviewed, I'd like to propose the option to re-flag. But if my retracted flag is still in review, I'd like to propose a clear stated text somewhere on the flag history page under the flag in question so I can relax knowing something is still going to be done.

Comment: 'Voting to close' has the same behaviour, it's not limited to flagging. See [Why can't we vote to close a question after the original vote was retracted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254778/247702)

Comment: @Stijn I sadly do not have enough reputation for that privilege. Thus flagging is my only option.

Comment: This might violate the bolded warning at the top, but I feel compelled to point out that "low quality" is very rarely an appropriate flag choice for a question. Its meaning is very ambiguous; you should prefer to choose one of the concrete reasons that expresses what is actually wrong with the question. "Low quality" should be used only when you want a moderator to insta-delete the question, even though it is neither spam nor offensive.

Comment: The fact that flags can be retracted are already highly non-trivial, due to possible abuse. What would stop you from flagging and unflagging stuff many times? Nobody wants that. It's already a miracle that you can re-cast other kind of flags...I missed this a lot in the older system (when after flagging NAA I realized that I would want to cast a custom mod flag instead).

Comment: Silly, I'm frustrated with the same thing. Flagged as "Duplicate", wrote comment for OP, researched further, realized "Close Question→Too Broad" would be better. Retracted 1st flag but then both flag options were disabled.  Clicked "Low Quality" to see what detail choices it would give me; it has none.  So now that flag is locked in, can't retract, and **PLUS, Now** (without a place to explain myself to reviewer), it probably appears that I was just screwing around or something...perhaps there should be a warnings like "Retracting won't allow you to choose a different flag".

Answer (score 13):

When you flagged the question as too broad, it was put in the Close Vote review queue. Retracting the flag does *not* remove the question from the review queue, if I interpret [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags#comment913503_281010) by Shog9 ♦ correctly:

> flags can set things into motion even before they're acted on, so allowing you to retract flags and re-cast them elsewhere would potentially allow you to circumvent limits in a number of rather disruptive ways.

So in this case, there's no need to cast the flag again. The only purpose retracting this flag had is that it could no longer be disputed/declined.

Comment: "allowing you to retract flags and re-cast them elsewhere would potentially allow you to circumvent limits in a number of rather disruptive ways" That's not true because [retracting a flag doesn't increment your daily flag allowance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010#comment912712_281010).