# Does Retract Flag lead to flag ban?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-ban, retracted-flags

What happens if I retract flag more number of times? Does it lead to flag ban?

Comment: If that would be true users would hold back on correcting their own mistakes. I'm pretty sure retracting a flag that hasn't been handled yet, doesn't lead to a flag ban

Comment: I wasn't aware that flags could be retracted until I saw your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Retracting a flag simply resolves it as "self-cleared" in your flag history. This has no side effects, but it doesn't reimburse the flag you spent so it's still not an excuse to flag carelessly.

Comment: what is the percent/ ratio of helpful : non-helpful flags to palce a ban

Comment: It also prevents you from flagging that question again, and the interface doesn't warn about this.  Sometimes, an edit turns a question from "Too broad" or "Unclear what you're asking" to something like "Recommend an off-site resource", but retracting the first flag prevents you from raising a new, more accurate flag.

Comment: As @KevinJ.Chase said, I also found this the hard way. I once raised an incorrect flag. I retracted it, and then, when I wanted to raise a new flag - both the correct reason and the one I have chosen before were grayed out.

Comment: Related to both my point about re-flagging and BoltClock's about "not an excuse to flag carelessly": "[Retracted flag does not let me flag again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333542)".

Comment: @Kevin J. Chase: I actually sympathize with your predicament - flagging a question for a reason that once applied but no longer does isn't exactly careless I don't think. My remark on careless flagging refers to people who simply don't flag wisely in the first place.

Comment: @BoltClock:  No offense taken, and I hope I didn't sound like I was arguing.  I guess I started this tangent mostly to give the "no reflagging" drawback some visibility, since the UI doesn't warn the user, either when flagging or when retracting a flag.  (I could try to justify it by claiming re-flag prevention is an _extremely narrow_ form of flag-ban, and thus relevant to the original question, but no one's falling for that.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase The UI *does* notify you about this when retracting an actual close vote, for what that's worth.

Comment: Retracting an upvote on a comment, second-class citizens as they are, warns you that you won't be able to upvote it again.

Comment: There are lots of things you can retract that all have different effects, but I'm fairly sure it's just flags we're talking about here.