# Change image on expanded usercard

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

Today I saw an image changing when hovering the profile picture of a user (*[@BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)*):

## Normal card:

[image]

## Expanded card:

[image]

Tested on this [**Meta question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345766/does-retract-flag-lead-to-flag-ban)

---

How did BoltClock do that?