# Allow re-flagging if an answer is edited after retraction

Tags: feature-request, edits, flags

Situation:

1. Answer is flagged (reason does not matter)
2. Answer is then edited, negating the need for the flag.
3. I retract the flag, as it's no longer appropriate.
4. The previous edit is reverted, so the flag is again appropriate.

I'm unable to re-flag the answer in this situation, because I'd previously retracted it. To me, this seems like common sense, in the same way that votes on questions and answers can be changed (no matter the time) after an edit.

Note that this isn't quite the same as [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333542/retracted-flag-does-not-let-me-flag-again?rq=1), as there's an edit between. I'm not just retracting and re-flagging with nothing else.

Comment: "in the same way that votes can be changed" This is true, but not on comments (if you vote for it, then remove your vote and then try again to vote).

Comment: @chade_ Comments are **way** not as important as questions.

Comment: @chade_ I personally think this should change as well, especially if there is an edit between. It's far less of an issue as flagging, though.

Comment: I flagged a question as duplicate of wrong post, and I wanted to retract the flag and re-flag as duplicate of the correct post, but I was unable to do that after retraction, so yes, this feature request will solve those cases as well.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me often.

I think it would also be useful to just be able to re-flag anyway.

I once flagged a question as duplicate. The OP told me it wasn't so I retracted the flag. I later realised after the OP posted another comment that it was in fact a duplicate. At this point I could not re-flag.