# Can't retract VLQ flag on a question after it was edited

Tags: bug, edits, flags, low-quality-posts, retracted-flags

I flagged a question as VLQ. The flag is still pending. Now the question has been edited into an actual question. I don't get an option to retract the flag. The flag popup just looks like this:

[image: flag popup]

There's no mention of VLQ flag, and no option to retract it.

Comment: You can check your flag history in your profile if you can retract it there.

Comment: for reference, this [apparently used to be possible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267561/what-should-i-do-if-an-edit-invalidates-my-flag)

Comment: @Tom The flag is in my flag history, but that does not give me a way to retract it.

Comment: @KevinB It's generally possible to retract pending flags, but in this case VLQ is missing from the flag popup, so there's no way to retract it.

Comment: Hmmm, this is particularly strange because the question you raised it on has been edited since (via a rollback), which should have marked it helpful...

Comment: Anyway I marked it helpful but it's definitely a bug.